# How to get the smallest elements in each column and assign them into new array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a C program which generates random numbers and fills array 5X5. 
How I can get the smallest element form each column and fill new array?
My program is finding only the smallest number from the whole array matrix.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define M 5

void print(int (*array)[M]);
int smallest(int array[M][M]);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int array[M][M], minScore;
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k<M; k++)
        {
            array[i][k] =-10 + rand() % 21;
        }
    }
    print(array);
    minScore = smallest(array);
    printf("Minimum is: %i\n", minScore);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void print(int (*array)[M])
{
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<M; k++)
        {
            printf("%d ",array[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int smallest(int array[M][M])
{
    int minValue;

    minValue = array[0][0];

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)
        {
            if ( array[i][k] < minValue)
                minValue = array [i][k];
        }
    }
    return minValue;

}
```

Comment: Do not use single-letter `#define`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the `minValue` after traversing each and every column, and assign them to the array after every column. Since, this has to be done for every column.

```
for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    minValue = array[0][i];
    for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)
    {
        if ( array[k][i] < minValue) 
            //here we are using array[k][i] and not array[i][k] since you need to traverse column wise
            minValue = array [k][i];
    }
    //--> here assign the minValue to the array you want
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function `int smallestInColumn(int array[M][M], int k)` where `k` is the column you want to inspect. Within that, just run the `i` loop.

(Then refactor `int smallest` to call that function when looping just over `k`).

By the way, using `% 21` to generate a random number will introduce statistical bias, unless your random number generator's periodicity is a multiple of 21, which is unlikely.

Comment: I know that %21 is not good way to generate numbers between -10 and 10 but it was the easiest way. May be I will try to make it more correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this something like this

```
//...

int smallest( int a[M][M], int column )
{
    int minValue = a[0][column];

    for ( int i = 1; i < M; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i][column] < minValue ) minValue = a[i][column];
    }

    return minValue;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[M][M];
    int b[M];

    //...

    for ( int i = 0; i < M; i++ ) b[i] = smallest( a, i );

    //...
}
```